# How can I have a tabbed app in Android like Spotify does?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tabbar, android-tabbed-activity

I'm totally new to Android development. I even don't know the name of components yet, something that make a bit harder to find how can I reach my goals.

Now my main goal is to desing a screen with a bottom tabbed bar, where the user can click in the tabs and the body of the screen changes, like the Spotify's do.

This image shows exactly what I'm looking for with those five icons at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for navigation bottom bar.

Link for design guidelines:
https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html

Link for example library implementation: https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation